# Numpy linear solver in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I was using numpy.linalg.solve to solve a set of linear equations, the coefficient matrix a is

```
a = [[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 ...,   0.00000000e+00
        0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
    [   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 ...,   0.00000000e+00
        0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
    [   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00 ...,   0.00000000e+00
        0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
    ..., 
    [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 ...,   1.19206809e+12
       -1.22559480e+12   3.46092750e+11]
    [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 ...,  -1.80896480e+14
       2.54068164e+12  -8.65658340e+12]
    [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 ...,   6.92185500e+11
       4.23578160e+12  -6.79632634e+12]]
```

and b matrix is

```
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ..........................150000]
```

and I think it should output the matrix like [0.0, 0.0]

However, the actual results is non-zeros value, can anyone help me figure out the reason?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that all your rows are linearly independent? Maybe you can try `numpy.linalg.inv(a)` and see what the output is.

Comment: It can be hard interpreting what comes out of the inverse, especially with large matrices. Rather calculate the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) using [numpy.linalg.cond](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html).